# Recursive Query runs indefinitely

Tags: sql-server-2008, recursion

Hi I am trying to run a recusrive query in SQL Server 2008. For specific values, the query seems to run forever. For other values, it is very quick (<5s)
Is there anything I could do in sql to prevent query running for more than say 10s?

```
    WITH tree (FID,TID, level) AS  (
      SELECT FID, TID, 1 as level
      FROM table1
      WHERE FID = '202223268'

      UNION ALL

      SELECT child.FID, child.TID, parent.level + 1
      FROM table1 as child
      JOIN tree parent on parent.TID = child.FID
      )
       SELECT FID,TID
       FROM tree
       option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldnt say you can limit the execution timeout on query basis (you can on server level), but if you limit the recursion depth (option maxrecursion) you can achieve very similar result.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I need a way to avoid infinite recursion. In Oracle, connect by nocycle prior seems to work. Is there an equivalent in SQL Server ??